# Is there any problem with using php native functions setcookie or using $_SERVER?

Tags: magento2

We have a sdk in php needed to be used by some Megento websites so we are extending that as a magento module. In our SDK we used php native fuctions and arrays. For example to find out what is the current request url is a wrong practice to use $_SERVER or to set cookie using php setcookie could cause any problem?

Answer (score 0):

just make you are on php version 7.0, as this may be a php 7.1 problem